# How to identify date falls in which quarter |Oracle SQL |

Tags: sql, oracle

I am bit stuck at this part not getting how to write query for it

Have basic knowledge on SQL , no idea about CASE statement

Need to find my date falls in which Quarter and print output in this format `BYYYY : Q12017`

B    : means => **Quarter**

YYYY : means =>  **Year**

The date format is : `'dd-MON-yy' : '1-JAN-20'`

As the above date falls in Quarter 1 so my output will be return : Q12017

Can some one explain how it can be achieved ?

I tried to do it with below approach

Do substr for date -> cut date , month , year and then how to check where it falls in which quarter ?

Comment: What DBMS do you use? Some of them have a function to get the quarter from a date.

Comment: @stickybit  : Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dates are calendar quarters (Jan - Mar, Apr - Jun, etc.) and your column is stored as a `date`, then you can express this as with a format in `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(datecol, 'YYYY"Q"Q')
```

Comment: checking the querying

Comment: @rixeh46662 . . . I'm surprised you don't prefer this (simple) solution.  Does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_char()` with `Q` and `YYYY` format specifiers and concatenation.

```
... to_char(<your date column>, 'YYYY') || 'Q' || to_char(<your date column>, 'Q') ...
```

Comment: bro it work partially -> i need to print : 20214 => but need => 2021Q4

Comment: @rixeh46662: Then split the `to_char()` in two and use concatenation. See the edit.